# printing a remote document on a local machine

Tags: web-applications, printing

My client is currently using a PHP application that displays an order dashboard, this dashboard is updated in real-time with new content using polling in the browser.

on the poll event i would like to pop up a print dialog to print a document for a particular order that was generated and stored on server.

So basically every order is stored as a receipt in pdf format on my webserver, all i need to do is when the dashboard is updated with new order i have to initiate a print on the local printer attached to the machine for a particular receipt.

is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP but I would say you could just initiate a download from the server that generated it and have the user save/open and print.  There should be several questions here on stackoverflow about downloading files in php.  This obviously requires that the files generated be accessible via the web.